# How do I compose /api/v1/users/id/{id} in net/http?

Tags: go

For example, I want to do `/api/v1/users/id/{id}`.

At the moment, I have this:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/api/v1/users", HandleUsersV1{db: db, mux: mux})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", ":", portNumber), mux))
```

I want:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/api/v1", HandleV1{})
```

And then in `HandleV1`:

```
mux.HandleFunc("/users/{id}", handler)
```

I know Gorilla Mux can do it for me with `PathPrefix`, but I prefer `net/http`.

Comment: It sounds like you really want Gorilla mux. It's not clear why you have rejected it.

Comment: I prefer using Golang default handlers then gorilla handlers. I'm trying to limit the use of frameworks.

Comment: Well, you can reinvent the wheel, write some terribly complicated router of your own, or use a library that is actually worth using. Mux is not really a framework; it's a very lightweight library. I think you have rejected it because you want to limit outside dependencies, but mux is _so useful_ that it's worth including in just about any project that serves HTTP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard `net/http` does not support dynamic path segments, so `/{id}` is not gonna work the way you might imagine. As for the prefix thing, you can use this https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix.

```
v1mux := http.NewServeMux()
v1mux.HandleFunc("/users/", handler)

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/api/v1/", http.StripPrefix("/api/v1", v1mux))

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", ":", portNumber), mux))
```

Comment: Thank's alot!
it works; unfortunately if I enter /api/v1/ by itself, it will strip it from the URL which is an unfortunate side effect of this.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter. But if you insist.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    res := resourceone{}
    http.HandleFunc("/api/v1/users/", res.router)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

type resourceone struct {
}

func (res *resourceone) router(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    args := strings.Split(r.URL.String()[len(`/api/v1/users/`):], `/`)
    switch args[0] {
    case `id`:
        id, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[1])
        res.one(w, r, id)
    case `name`:
        res.two(w, r, args[1])
    }
}

func (res *resourceone) one(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, id int) {
    w.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(id)))
}

func (res *resourceone) two(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, name string) {
    w.Write([]byte(name))
}
```

Test:

`curl 127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/users/name/david`

`curl 127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/users/id/1234`

Comment: This answer could use more explanation and less criticism of OP's choice of library.

Comment: The `if you insist` said with humor. I eventually took the time to write something in order to try to help. Although if @Flimzy say something about that I would love to apologise. I think drawing the politically correct gun for every little thing do not do good to any community. I also think the code is straight forward I'll be happy to elaborate if someone ask to.